# Prevent Windows 8 users from accessing Windows 7 files

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, user-accounts

I have set up Windows 7 and Windows 8 dual boot. From Windows 8, users have access to my Windows 7 C:\ drive and all its files, including files in C:\Users\username\ How to take care of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go to Disk Management (search "Administrative Tools" on the Start Screen in settings, then choose Computer Management, then Disk Management), right-click the Windows 7 drive and choose *Change Drive Letters and Paths*. Remove all letters from this drive and it will become inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Reboot in Windows 7 and log in under an admin account.
2. Run the command prompt **cmd** as Administrator.
3. Type the following commands

   takeown /F C:\Users\user_name  /a  /r  /d y

   cacls C:\Users\user_name /t /g Administrators:F System:F (Type Y and press Enter to the prompt "Are you sure")

   cacls "C:\Users\user_name" /e /t /g "user_name":F

Answer (score 0):

Just change the security settings. Right click on the folder -> Properties -> Security tab